# unable to display selected value in mozilla browser when using angular2 forms

Tags: angular

I have a basic form which has a select box...Whenever user makes changes i am trying to display the selected value...I have made a plunker demo http://plnkr.co/edit/Ob26yFN5ohVNpMeMWuvr?p=preview ...this demo works fine in chrome browser but not in mozilla and microsoft edge...The problem is whenever change event is executed the changed value is not reflecting in the control group...I dont know why this issue is arising... Is this a problem of browser or angular2 framework? Somebody please tell me why is this not working...
This is my change event

```
  changed(){
console.log(this.myForm.controls['select'].value);
this.SelectedData=this.myForm.controls['select'].value;
 }
```

Thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

That is a known issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6573

As a workaround you can use

```
<select [ngModel]="value" (change)="changeValue($event.target.value)">
```